# How to hide <matplotlib.lines.Line2D> in IPython notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am plotting a NumPy array of values, `I`, using IPython notebook in `%matplotlib` inline mode with the plot command `plt.plot(I,'o')`.

The resulting output is:

```
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x119e6ead0>
Out[159]:
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x11ac57090>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x11ac57310>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x11ac57510>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x11ac57690>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x11ac57810>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x11ac57990>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x11ac57b10>,
 ....
 ....
]
```

Then my plot shows up below these lines of output.

Is there a way to just show the plot and hide the `<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at ...>` from the output?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You can use a semi-colon `;` to end the line. This suppresses the unwanted output when generating plots:

```
plt.plot(I,'o');
```

In general, using a semi-colon stops IPython from printing any output value from that line of a code block. For example, the executing the cell containing the code `1+1;` would not output `2`.

An alternative way would be to bind a variable to the plot:

```
_ = plt.plot(a)
```

This way, IPython only shows you the plots and the name `_` is bound to the unwanted output.

Answer (score 23):

Another way is to just write `plt.show()` at the end of your drawing code. It would take less symbols to type if you're generating many subplots and/or drawing many plots on a single subplot.

Answer (score 0):

Old question...
Well I prefer to use a `pass` in the last line.

Not so small like `;`, but, IMHO, more legible and yet short.