# How to plot a histogram using Matplotlib in Python with a list of data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, visualization, histogram

If I have a list of y-values that correspond to bar height and a list of x-value strings, how do I plot a histogram using [`matplotlib.pyplot.hist`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html)?

Related: [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html).

Comment: If you plotted a histogram using `.bar` but it doesn’t look correct, then probably the bars are too wide. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78104727/19123103) to adjust the bar width.

Answer (score 295):

If you want a histogram, you don't need to attach any 'names' to x-values because:

- on `x`-axis you will have data bins
- on `y`-axis counts (by default) or frequencies (`density=True`)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

np.random.seed(42)
x = np.random.normal(size=1000)

plt.hist(x, density=True, bins=30)  # density=False would make counts
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.xlabel('Data');
```

[image]

Note, the number of `bins=30` was chosen arbitrarily, and there is [Freedman–Diaconis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedman%E2%80%93Diaconis_rule) rule to be more scientific in choosing the "right" bin width:

> [image: ![enter image description here] , where `IQR` is [Interquartile range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range) and `n` is total number of datapoints to plot

So, according to this rule one may calculate number of `bins` as:

```
q25, q75 = np.percentile(x, [25, 75])
bin_width = 2 * (q75 - q25) * len(x) ** (-1/3)
bins = round((x.max() - x.min()) / bin_width)
print("Freedman–Diaconis number of bins:", bins)
plt.hist(x, bins=bins);
```

---

```
Freedman–Diaconis number of bins: 82
```

[image]

And finally you can make your histogram a bit fancier with `PDF` line, titles, and legend:

```
import scipy.stats as st

plt.hist(x, density=True, bins=82, label="Data")
mn, mx = plt.xlim()
plt.xlim(mn, mx)
kde_xs = np.linspace(mn, mx, 300)
kde = st.gaussian_kde(x)
plt.plot(kde_xs, kde.pdf(kde_xs), label="PDF")
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.ylabel("Probability")
plt.xlabel("Data")
plt.title("Histogram");
```

[image]

If you're willing to explore other opportunities, there is a shortcut with `seaborn`:

```
# !pip install seaborn
import seaborn as sns
sns.displot(x, bins=82, kde=True);
```

[image]

Now back to the OP.

If you have limited number of data points, a bar plot would make more sense to represent your data. Then you may attach labels to x-axis:

```
x = np.arange(3)
plt.bar(x, height=[1,2,3])
plt.xticks(x, ['a','b','c']);
```

[image]

Comment: @Toad22222 This is an excerpt from Ipython notebook cell. Try to execute it without semicolon and see the difference. All the code snippets I post on SO run perfectly on my computer.

Comment: If you are wondering about the semi-colon used by Sergey, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25790062/how-to-hide-matplotlib-lines-line2d-in-ipython-notebook) and [#16 here](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/jupyter-notebook-tips-tricks-shortcuts/) for how semi-colon is used in Jupyter notebooks (formerly IPython notebooks) cells when plotting to suppress the text about the plot object.

Comment: If you are getting **OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer**
just change .25 to 25 and .75 to 75

Answer (score 27):

If you haven't installed matplotlib yet just try the command.

```
> pip install matplotlib
```

#### Library import

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
```

#### The histogram data:

```
plot.hist(weightList,density=1, bins=20) 
plot.axis([50, 110, 0, 0.06]) 
#axis([xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax])
plot.xlabel('Weight')
plot.ylabel('Probability')
```

#### Display histogram

```
plot.show()
```

#### And the output is like :

[image]

Comment: The plot.axis([50, 110, 0, 0.06])' line is useless for the example. Besides, as it hard codes the area of the plot to show, if your data does not fit entirely inside it you may be confused why it doesn't show correctly.

Answer (score 7):

Though the question appears to be demanding plotting a histogram using `matplotlib.hist()` function, it can arguably be not done using the same as the latter part of the question demands to use the given probabilities as the y-values of bars and given names(strings) as the x-values.

I'm assuming a sample list of names corresponding to given probabilities to draw the plot. A simple bar plot serves the purpose here for the given problem. The following code can be used:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
probability = [0.3602150537634409, 0.42028985507246375, 
  0.373117033603708, 0.36813186813186816, 0.32517482517482516, 
  0.4175257731958763, 0.41025641025641024, 0.39408866995073893, 
  0.4143222506393862, 0.34, 0.391025641025641, 0.3130841121495327, 
  0.35398230088495575]
names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5', 'name6', 'name7', 'name8', 'name9',
'name10', 'name11', 'name12', 'name13'] #sample names
plt.bar(names, probability)
plt.xticks(names)
plt.yticks(probability) #This may be included or excluded as per need
plt.xlabel('Names')
plt.ylabel('Probability')
```

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question but none of the previous answers has addressed the real issue, i.e. that fact that the problem is with the question itself.

First, if the probabilities have been already calculated, i.e. the histogram aggregated data is available in a normalized way then the probabilities should add up to 1. They obviously do not and that means that something is wrong here, either with terminology or with the data or in the way the question is asked.

Second, the fact that the labels are provided (and not intervals) would normally mean that the probabilities are of categorical response variable - and a use of a bar plot for plotting the histogram is best (or some hacking of the pyplot's hist method), Shayan Shafiq's answer provides the code.

However, see issue 1, those probabilities are not correct and using bar plot in this case as "histogram" would be wrong because it does not tell the story of univariate distribution, for some reason (perhaps the classes are overlapping and observations are counted multiple times?) and such plot should not be called a histogram in this case.

Histogram is by definition a graphical representation of the distribution of univariate variable (see [Histogram | NIST/SEMATECH e-Handbook of Statistical Methods](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/histogra.htm) & [Histogram | Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram)) and is created by drawing bars of sizes representing counts or frequencies of observations in selected classes of the variable of interest. If the variable is measured on a continuous scale those classes are bins (intervals). Important part of histogram creation procedure is making a choice of how to group (or keep without grouping) the categories of responses for a categorical variable, or how to split the domain of possible values into intervals (where to put the bin boundaries) for continuous type variable. All observations should be represented, and each one only once in the plot. That means that the sum of the bar sizes should be equal to the total count of observation (or their areas in case of the variable widths, which is a less common approach). Or, if the histogram is normalised then all probabilities must add up to 1.

If the data itself is a list of "probabilities" as a response, i.e. the observations are probability values (of something) for each object of study then the best answer is simply `plt.hist(probability)` with maybe binning option, and use of x-labels already available is suspicious.

Then bar plot should not be used as histogram but rather simply

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
probability = [0.3602150537634409, 0.42028985507246375, 
  0.373117033603708, 0.36813186813186816, 0.32517482517482516, 
  0.4175257731958763, 0.41025641025641024, 0.39408866995073893, 
  0.4143222506393862, 0.34, 0.391025641025641, 0.3130841121495327, 
  0.35398230088495575]
plt.hist(probability)
plt.show()
```

with the results

[image]

matplotlib in such case arrives by default with the following histogram values

```
(array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 0., 2., 0., 4.]),
 array([0.31308411, 0.32380469, 0.33452526, 0.34524584, 0.35596641,
        0.36668698, 0.37740756, 0.38812813, 0.39884871, 0.40956928,
        0.42028986]),
 <a list of 10 Patch objects>)
```

the result is a tuple of arrays, the first array contains observation counts, i.e. what will be shown against the y-axis of the plot (they add up to 13, total number of observations) and the second array are the interval boundaries for x-axis.

One can check they they are equally spaced,

```
x = plt.hist(probability)[1]
for left, right in zip(x[:-1], x[1:]):
  print(left, right, right-left)
```

[image]

Or, for example for 3 bins (my judgment call for 13 observations) one would get this histogram

```
plt.hist(probability, bins=3)
```

[image]

with the plot data "behind the bars" being

[image]

The author of the question needs to clarify what is the meaning of the "probability" list of values - is the "probability" just a name of the response variable (then why are there x-labels ready for the histogram, it makes no sense), or are the list values the probabilities calculated from the data (then the fact they do not add up to 1 makes no sense).

Comment: You NAILED it!  The question is flawed.  Good catch.

Answer (score 5):

This is a very round-about way of doing it but if you want to make a histogram where you already know the bin values but dont have the source data, you can use the `np.random.randint` function to generate the correct number of values within the range of each bin for the hist function to graph, for example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [np.random.randint(0, 9, *desired y value*), np.random.randint(10, 19, *desired y value*), etc..]
plt.hist(data, histtype='stepfilled', bins=[0, 10, etc..])
```

as for labels you can align x ticks with bins to get something like this:

```
#The following will align labels to the center of each bar with bin intervals of 10
plt.xticks([5, 15, etc.. ], ['Label 1', 'Label 2', etc.. ])
```

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR: If you have raw data, you probably need `hist()`; if you have processed data, you probably need `bar()`.

For a 1D array (or a flat list) of data, `plt.hist` is just a wrapper around `np.histogram` and `plt.bar`. In particular, since it's often the case that `hist` ends up drawing a lot of bars (which correspond to frequency in each bin) compared to `bar`, bar widths are adjusted by `np.diff(bins)` ([source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/39582424f8ce5e042e4e39eeac94893f222c9f8b/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L6877-L6896)). The main "functionality" of `hist` can be abbreviated as follows:

```py
height, bins = np.histogram(data, bins)    # compute histogram
width = np.diff(bins)                      # calculate bar width
boffset = 0.5 * width                      # calculate bar position offset
plt.bar(bins[:-1]+boffset, height, width)  # plot bar-chart
```

So if the input is

> a list of y-values that correspond to bar height

then `hist` most likely won't behave as you would expect it to because it bins that raw input and counts the number of data points in each bin, i.e. it would process your data even further "thinking" it's raw input. If you have a list of probability values, i.e. height of the bars in a histogram, then you can go ahead and plot a bar-chart instead.

---

An example may be illustrative. Say, you have a raw data with 1000 data points.

```py
raw_data = np.random.default_rng(0).normal(size=1000)
raw_data.shape   # (1000,)
```

To plot its histogram, we need to specify the number of bins ([Sergey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33203848/19123103) includes a way to calculate the *correct* number of bins). Let's plot `raw_data` with 20 bins (which means we have a bar-chart with 20 bars).

```py
counts, bin_edges, *_ = plt.hist(raw_data, bins=20)
```

[image: result]

However, if you already have the `counts` (or frequencies or bar heights) and bin edges, like:

```py
counts = [2, 0, 4, 3, 9, 13, 34, 68, 88, 131, 149, 128, 124, 
          95, 71, 40, 25, 9, 5, 2]

bin_edges = [-3.9, -3.55, -3.2, -2.85, -2.51, -2.16, -1.81, 
             -1.46, -1.11, -0.76, -0.42, -0.07, 0.28, 0.63, 
             0.98, 1.32, 1.67, 2.02, 2.37, 2.72, 3.07]
```

then instead of `hist`, use `bar` instead; simply plotting like `plt.bar(bin_edges[:-1], counts)` works if there are very few bars, i.e. number of bins is low. But if there are a lot of bars, this would not plot a very accurate histogram. We need to adjust the bar widths (like in the source code) to create a bar-chart that matches the `plt.hist` call on the raw data:

```py
width = np.diff(bin_edges)                           # bar widths
boffset = 0.5 * width                                # bar position offsets
plt.bar(bin_edges[:-1]+boffset, counts, width)       # bar-chart
```

It's left to the reader to verify that this `plt.bar` call with the adjusted bar widths creates the same figure as created by the `plt.hist` call (on the raw data) above.