# Plot histogram of Benford law

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to plot Benford's law

```
#+begin_src ipython :session alinbx :results none
from math import log10, log
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10.00, 6.18 )

def benford(n):
    return log10(n+1) - log10(n)

results = [benford(i) for i in range(1, 10)]
plt.plot(list(range(1,10)), results)
#+end_src
```

Run and get the result

[image]

The result I want is

[image]

Create histogram

```
#+begin_src ipython :session alinbx :results drawer
plt.hist(results,bins=9)
plt.axis([1, 10, 1])
#+end_src
```

but got the results

[image]

Then I spent hours reading:

- https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-pyplot-py
- https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/statistics/hist.html
- [How to plot a histogram using Matplotlib in Python with a list of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203645/how-to-plot-a-histogram-using-matplotlib-in-python-with-a-list-of-data)

I merely release that one should be super master at matplotlib before get this easy task done.

Could you please provide any hints?

Comment: You want to do a bar plot, not a histogram https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/custom_ticker1.html#sphx-glr-gallery-ticks-and-spines-custom-ticker1-py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to plot a bar plot, not a histogram. You can do that as following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import log10


def benford(n):
    return log10(n+1) - log10(n)


x = [i for i in range(1, 10)]
results = [benford(i) for i in x]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.bar(x, results)
plt.xticks(x, x)
plt.show()
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDOBd.png]

Answer (score 1):

The original plot that you show is a bar plot, not an histogram. Running your exact code with `plt.bar(list(range(1,10)), results)` instead of `plt.hist(list(range(1,10)), results)` results in: 
[image]