# using the matplotlib .pylot for drawing histogram and the smooth curve which lies on the histogram

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram, curve

I have tried to draw a histogram using matplotlib and the pandas but while drawing the smooth curve it gave me an error I can you please help to resolve this and maybe give me some method to draw the smooth curve on histogram using matplotlib I am trying not to use any another library (seaborn) here is the code

```
mu,sigma = 100,15   
plt.style.use('dark_background')
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)
n,bins,patches = plt.hist(x,bins=50,density=1,facecolor='g',alpha = 0.5)
zee=bins[:-1]
plt.plot(np.round(zee),patches,'ro')
plt.xlabel('Smarts')
plt.ylabel('Probablity')
plt.title('Histogram of the Iq')
plt.axis([40,160,0,0.03])
plt.grid(1)
plt.show()
```

the error shown is

```
 python3 -u "/home/somesh/Downloads/vscode_code/python ml course /firstml.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/somesh/Downloads/vscode_code/python ml course /firstml.py", line 149, in <module>
    plt.plot(np.round(zee),patches,'ro')
  File "/home/somesh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2840, in plot
    return gca().plot(
  File "/home/somesh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1745, in plot
    self.add_line(line)
  File "/home/somesh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 1964, in add_line
    self._update_line_limits(line)
  File "/home/somesh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 1986, in _update_line_limits
    path = line.get_path()
  File "/home/somesh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 1011, in get_path
    self.recache()
  File "/home/somesh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 658, in recache
    y = _to_unmasked_float_array(yconv).ravel()
  File "/home/somesh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 1289, in _to_unmasked_float_array
    return np.asarray(x, float)
  File "/home/somesh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Rectangle'
```

and is this possible to draw the smooth curve using only the matplotlib library

edit 1: thanks for the answer I was finally able to spot the error
[image]

Comment: `patches` are rectangles, so you should not be plotting anything them against anything. I think you want to plot `n` against `zee`.

Comment: but n's size is different and it's showing the argument must be string or the number not rectangle

Comment: You should definitely try again :-).

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/33203848/4317058

Comment: is this not possible without using the scipy's library

Comment: or only with the help of the matplotlib

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov the answer you have mentioned draws the pdf curve It doesn't cover's all the points (edit: all the top of the hist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `zee` is a matplotlibobject Rectangle object. However, the plot function need a `float` as input.

Since what you are plotting is a normal distribution. Also, you like the curve to be smooth. So why not generate a normal distribution and plot it into same figure. Here is a modified version of your code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as stats

mu,sigma = 100,15   
plt.style.use('dark_background')
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)
n,bins,patches = plt.hist(x,bins=50,density=1,facecolor='g',alpha = 0.5)

# zee=bins[:-1]
# plt.plot(np.round(zee),patches,'ro')
x_overlay = np.linspace(mu - 3*sigma, mu + 3*sigma, 100)
plt.plot(x_overlay, stats.norm.pdf(x_overlay, mu, sigma),"ro")

plt.xlabel('Smarts')
plt.ylabel('Probablity')
plt.title('Histogram of the Iq')
plt.axis([40,160,0,0.03])
plt.grid(1)
plt.show()
```

Output of the plot:
[image]

Comment: Why do we need to find the pdf of the function we can do the same thing with the
`
plt.plot(np.round(zee),n,'ro')
`

Comment: I though you was looking for a theoretical description of your data. That's what I am guessing your "smooth curve" mean. You can do a fitting too, if you are processing real data.

Answer (score 0):

`n` has the same size with `zee`, which is `length(bins)-1`:

```
mu,sigma = 100,15   
plt.style.use('dark_background')
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)
n,bins,patches = plt.hist(x,bins=50,density=1,facecolor='g',alpha = 0.5)
zee=bins[:-1]

## this
plt.plot(np.round(zee),n,'ro')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes I was exactly looking for this