# Pymongo and Matplotlib

Tags: python, mongodb, matplotlib, pymongo, histogram

How do I generate graphs with matplotlib that show the distribution values of some variables of a JSON file? for example in this picture, i need to make a hist graph of "borough"(im using pymongo at a notebook)
[image]

im expecting to see a histogram of "borough"

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541)? Likely useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this ?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [i for i in range(len(query_borough)]
h = [doc['result'] for doc in query_borough]
t = [doc['_id'] for doc in query_borough]
plt.bar(x, height=h)
plt.xticks(x,t);
```

Based on [How to plot a histogram using Matplotlib in Python with a list of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203645/how-to-plot-a-histogram-using-matplotlib-in-python-with-a-list-of-data)