# Hide matplotlib descriptions in jupyter notebook

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am not sure what is the correct term for this, but here is what I see when I plot something:

[image]

The plots is actually what I want so see, but jupyter notebook also outputs some text: `<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x1263354d0>`, `<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x1263353d0>` which I am trying to get rid of.

After some searching, the only thing I was able to find is `plt.ioff()`, which didn't help me. Is there a way to get rid of the text?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25790062/how-to-hide-matplotlib-lines-line2d-in-ipython-notebook

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can finish the corresponding (matplotlib) line with a semicolon **;**

Comment: Works with `seaborn` too: `sns.lineplot(data=data, palette="tab10", linewidth=2.5);`

Comment: What an answer!

Answer (score 15):

This is a bit of a workaround, but it should work consistently:

**1. Assign the plotting function to a variable** (which could also be useful if you need to access some plot elements later on)

```
plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3))

plot = plt.plot(range(10),
                [x*x for x in range(10)],
                'o-')
```

**2. Add a "pass" at the bottom of the cell** (or an equivalent operation with no consequence)

```
plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3))

plt.plot(range(10),
         [x*x for x in range(10)],
         'o-')
pass
```

**3. Add a semicolon at the end of the last statement**

```
plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3))

plt.plot(range(10),
         [x*x for x in range(10)],
         'o-');
```